# Open netcdfs data in gz file

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I have netcdfs saved in a [gz file](https://github.com/kevinkuranyi/archive/blob/main/Maize_1970_Yield_ver12b_BRA.nc.gz) and I am trying to import as a geodataframe on python. I don't know the name of the variables in the netcdfs.

My code:

```
gzipped_file_path = 'Maize_1970_Yield_ver12b_BRA.nc.gz'


with gzip.open(gzipped_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    # Read the content of the gzipped file
    content = f.read()
```

This part works fine, but then, when trying to create a dataset, I'm trying:

```
df=nc.Dataset(content)
```

And it starts to run forever (it`s been running for over 3 hours as of now).
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I don't think that you can just dump the contents of the file inside nc.Dataset, you need to pass it name or file ID of the opened netCDF file.

Comment: @Dimitar , could you please clarify how to do it? It is my first time working with this kind of data

Comment: Okay I will write an answer

Comment: I have uploaded the code, you can just plug and play and see if it works. I'd remove the tag `gzip` and `gis` as they do not have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the `nc.Database` function expects to get a file name to an opened file, or a File ID.

So first, lets get the file opening ready:

```
import gzip, os
import netCDF4 as nc

gzipped_file_path = 'Maize_1970_Yield_ver12b_BRA.nc.gz'
temp_nc_path = 'temp_netcdf_file.nc'

with gzip.open(gzipped_file_path, 'rb') as f_in, open(temp_nc_path, 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(f_in.read())
```

Now, `f_out` is an opened file that essentially contains the contents of `f_in`, and you can work with the `nc.Database` function:

```
ds = nc.Dataset(temp_nc_path)
print(ds.variables.keys()) # check the keys
```

Finally, close the file and delete the temporary file in order to avoid garbage in your system and having to do maintenance on `tmp` folders later on:

```
ds.close()
os.remove(temp_nc_path)
```

That should do it.